# Codeigniter 3 HMVC has been broken

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc

Using this HMVC plugin in Codeigniter. (https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/src/codeigniter-3.x/)

Running fine in another server, but in this server I am getting this error!

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the current behavior

Filename: MX/Router.php

Line Number: 239

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/project.test/public/application/third_party/MX/Router.php
Line: 239
Function: strpos

File: /var/www/project.test/public/application/third_party/MX/Router.php
Line: 101
Function: _set_default_controller

File: /var/www/project.test/public/index.php
Line: 324
Function: require_once
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This server is running PHP 7, please have a look at this pull request:

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/pull-requests/39/php73-fix-for-error-message-strpos-non/diff

Comment: this link is dead

Answer (score 8):

I change the line of codes on the function set_class like this:

```
    {
        //this is the original codes I commented
    /* $suffix = $this->config->item('controller_suffix');
        if (strpos($class, $suffix) === FALSE)
        {
            $class .= $suffix;
        }
        parent::set_class($class); 
    */

      //and change with this one
        $suffix = (string) $this->config->item('controller_suffix');
        if ($suffix && strpos($class, $suffix) === FALSE) {
            $class .= $suffix;
        }

        parent::set_class($class);
    }

Source: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-72393.html
```

Answer (score 8):

> Just Update the function in Router.php
>   File Path: application\third_party\MX\Router.php

```
public function set_class($class)
    {
    //  $suffix = $this->config->item('controller_suffix');
    //  if (strpos($class, $suffix) === FALSE)

    $suffix = (string) $this->config->item('controller_suffix');
    if ($suffix && strpos($class, $suffix) === FALSE)
    {
        $class .= $suffix;
    }
    parent::set_class($class);
}
```

> After this it is working fine!

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
if (strpos($class, chr($suffix)) === FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This link is not working .It shows "Repository not found".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31851367)